# How to call _mm256_mul_ph from rust?

Tags: rust, intrinsics, avx512, half-precision-float

`_mm256_mul_ps` is the Intel intrinsic for "Multiply packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements". `_mm256_mul_ph` is the intrinsic for "Multiply packed half-precision (16-bit) floating-point elements ".

I can call `_mm256_mul_ps` from using using `use std::arch::x86_64::*;`, e.g.

```rust
#[inline]
fn mul(v: __m256, w: __m256) -> __m256 {
     unsafe { _mm256_mul_ps(v, w) }
}
```

However, it appears to be difficult to call [`_mm256_mul_ph`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=2245,2664,4687,2664,2938,678,137,684,6423,3675,3667,4687,4733,4753,4687,4733,4678,4678,4687,4690,4681,4681,4678&text=_mm256_mul_p). Can one call [`_mm256_mul_ph`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=2245,2664,4687,2664,2938,678,137,684,6423,3675,3667,4687,4733,4753,4687,4733,4678,4678,4687,4690,4681,4681,4678&text=_mm256_mul_p) in Rust?

Comment: I see no record of a function called `_mm256_add_ph` in [the module you reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/index.html), and the first google link when I search the function name is _this_ question. Do you have any evidence that such a function exists?

Comment: It does not look like any intrinsic from the [AVX512 FP16 instruction set](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.htm#avx512techs=AVX512_FP16) is available in `std::arch`.

Comment: The relevant [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/issues/310) on the `stdarch` repository on GitHub.

Comment: I fixed the link it now points to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=2245,2664,4687,2664,2938,678,137,684,6423,3675,3667,4687,4733,4753,4687,4733,4678,4678,4687,4690,4681,4681,4678&text=_mm256_mul_p

Comment: You linked `_mm256_mul_p[s,h]`, not `_mm256_add_p[s,h]`.

Comment: But it looks like these intrinsics [do exist](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=2245,2664,4687,2664,2938,678,137,684,6423,3675,3667,4687,4733,4753,4687,4733,4678,4678,4687,4690,4681,4681,4678,128&text=_mm256_add_p).

Comment: I made it now consistent for `mul`. `mul` or `add`. The problem. If there is a solution, likely the same solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for requires the AVX-512 FP16 and AVX-512 VL instruction sets - the former of which does not appear to have any support within Rust at the moment.

You can potentially create your own intrinsics as-needed by using the [`asm!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/macro.asm.html) macro. The assembly for `_mm256_mul_ph` looks like this:

```
vmulph ymm, ymm, ymm
```

So the equivalent in Rust would be written like so:

```
#[cfg(target_feature = "avx2")]
unsafe fn _mm256_mul_ph(a: __m256i, b: __m256i) -> __m256i {
    let dst: __m256i;

    asm!(
        "vmulph {0}, {1}, {2}",
        out(ymm_reg) dst,
        in(ymm_reg) a,
        in(ymm_reg) b,
        options(pure, nomem, nostack),
    );

    dst
}
```

To make your own intrinsics for other instructions, please ensure you follow the guidelines for Rust's [inline assembly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/inline-assembly.html) as well as careful understanding of what the instructions do. Inline assembly is `unsafe` and can cause very weird behavior if specified improperly.

Caveats:

- This only works since the underlying machinery (LLVM 17 as of Rust 1.76) *does* support this instruction set. If you attempt to try this method on a brand new instruction set (or with an older toolchain) it may not work and fail to compile due to an "invalid instruction".
- [`__m256i`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/arch/x86_64/struct.__m256i.html) is used in lieu of a `__m256h` type since the latter does not exist. Currently `__m256i` is used as a "bag of bits" (documentation's words) so you must keep track yourself that it is holding `f16x16` values.
- The `target_feature = "avx2"` condition is woefully inadequate for properly limiting it to targets that can actually run this function. There is no `avx512fp16` target feature flag available within Rust (`_mm256_mul_ph` in particular needs the `avx512vl` target feature flag as well but that also is not supported).

  You will either need to be careful that you only compile and run this code for architectures that support it - currently Intel Sapphire Rapids CPUs as far as I can tell. Or it might be better to introduce your own compilation flag which, while not perfect, would hopefully limit the scope of things going wrong.

  If compiled and executed on an unsupported architecture, you'll receive an "illegal instruction" error (in the best case).

Comment: The other caveat of course being that it's inline asm, not a real intrinsic, so constant-propagation and other optimizations (like tracking values through shuffles) can't happen through it.  And stuff like contracting mul+add into FMA.  And with AVX-512, folding a blend into a merge-masked output, or a load into a memory source operand.  (A mem src could be allowed with constraints if LLVM isn't going to shoot itself in the foot by always spilling like clang does.)  Once a real intrinsic exists, prefer that unless the optimizer is doing a bad job and you *want* to force this asm to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using FFI. Basically calling intrinsics from a compiled C code and linking this code with Rust.

Create a helper C file with a wrapper function and include `immintrin.h`. The :

`src/simp-helper.c`

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256i call_mm256_mul_ph(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
    return _mm256_mul_ph(a, b);
}

__m512d call_mm512_mul_pd(__m512d a, __m512d b) {
    return _mm512_mul_pd(a, b);
}
```

In your Rust source declare this helper function as external:

`src/main.rs`

```rust
#![feature(simd_ffi)]
#![feature(stdarch_x86_avx512)]
// Some types and functions are unstable an require 
// adding the features above and using the nightly toolchain
use std::arch::x86_64::{
    __m256, __m256i, __m512d, _mm256_castps_si256, _mm256_loadu_ps, _mm512_set1_pd,
};

// Declare the helper functions as extern "C"
extern "C" {
    fn call_mm256_mul_ph(a: __m256i, b: __m256i) -> __m256i;
    fn call_mm512_mul_pd(a: __m512d, b: __m512d) -> __m512d;
}

fn main() {
    // example 1: works only for CPU with AVX512_FP16
    unsafe {
        let a: [f32; 8] = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2];
        let fp32_v1: __m256 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.as_ptr());
        let fp32_pack_v1: __m256i = _mm256_castps_si256(fp32_v1);

        let b: [f32; 8] = [2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1];
        let fp32_v2: __m256 = _mm256_loadu_ps(b.as_ptr());
        let fp32_pack_v2: __m256i = _mm256_castps_si256(fp32_v2);

        let result = call_mm256_mul_ph(fp32_pack_v1, fp32_pack_v2);
        println!("{:?}", result);
    }
    // example 2: for AVX512F, to check that the approach works
    unsafe {
        let a: __m512d = _mm512_set1_pd(1.2);
        let b: __m512d = _mm512_set1_pd(2.1);
        let result = call_mm512_mul_pd(a, b);
        println!("{:?}", result);
    }
}
```

Notice the module features required for this example to work.

In order to build this, you need to compile C sources with the corresponding AVX flags. You can compile C sources directly in the Rust project with help of [cc crate](https://docs.rs/cc/latest/cc/) which compiles C/C++ files into a static library that you can link with Rust, and a custom `build.rs` file:

`Cargo.toml`

```toml
[package]
name = "intrinsic"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0"

[[bin]]
name = "mul_vec"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

`build.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/simd_helper.c");
    // Use the `cc` crate to build a C file and statically link it.
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/simd_helper.c")
        .flag("-mavx512f")
        .flag("-mavx512fp16")
        .compile("simd_helper");
    // Tell cargo to link the object file
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=.");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=simd_helper");
}
```

Important note that you need to build this with `+nightly` flag due to using unstable features.

```
cargo +nightly build
```

I don't have a machine with AVX512_FP16, so I used `_mm512_mul_pd` as an example to build and run on my machine.

Hope it would be helpful.
Full [cargo project on GitHub](https://github.com/arskov/intrinsic-example).

Comment: **A non-inline function wrapper around a single-instruction intrinsic would be a disaster for performance**, *much* worse than inline asm which is pretty close to real intrinsics, and the same if memory source operands or constant folding aren't a factor.  (Unless link-time optimization can inline a C function into a Rust caller?)  Neither x86-64 SysV nor Windows x64 have any call-preserved YMM or ZMM registers, so all vector variables would have to get spilled to stack memory, and you have call/ret overhead of a few uops and two taken branches.

Comment: Probably worse than using `__m512 _mm512_cvtph_ps(__m256i)` (AVX-512F, the 512-bit version of F16C conversion instructions) to convert to/from `__m512` single-precision float vectors around your math ops.